# Test Console.ReadLine(); input type

Tags: c#, function, parsing, recursion, types

I'm making a console app in which I'll ask the user for a phone number `int main_phone`, but if he types a string thats not convertible to int such as "Caramel" I want to give him a warning and ask for a number.

Well I thought a recursive function would do, but I'm lacking logical aptitude for this one. What I came up with was the following code snippet:

```
static int? TryParse(string str)
{
    int tmp;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out tmp)) {
        return tmp;
    }
    return null;
}//End of TryParse();
            
static int? verifyParse(string str, string lable)
{
    int? testedVar = TryParse(str);
    if (testedVar == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Este campo pode apenas conter dígitos de 0 à 9.");
        Console.Write(lable);
        verifyParse(Console.ReadLine(), lable);
        return null;
    }
    else 
    {
        return testedVar;
    }
}//End of verifyParse();
    
Console.Write("Phone(main):");              
int? main_phone = verifyParse(Console.ReadLine(),"Telefone (Principal):");
```

The problem is that if the user inputs "string" main_phone will comeback as null, then it asks for a number between 0 and 9, but even if the user passes a convertible string , such as "12", main_phone will still be null.

How can I fix that?

## EDIT 1:

What I really need is a function that if the string can be converted to an int it returns the int, else it gives me an error and asks me to input something between 0 and 9. I find this hard because the function would have to be able to return an int or run it self all over again(to require and test a valid input), but it can't because either it returns the int or it doesn't return nothing.

## EDIT 2:

Here is a little update on my problem:

```
static int TryParse(string lable)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
        
        while (!regex.IsMatch(str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insira apenas dígitos de 0-9, por favor.");
            Console.Write(lable);
            str = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(str);
    }//End of TryParse();

    Console.Write("Telefone (Principal):");             
    int main_phone = TryParse("Telefone (Principal):");
```

It works really well, except when I input something like "1a". In that case I'll get this error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at App1.Program.TryParse(String lable)
   at App1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Regex would be a good route.  Then you could accept numbers with hyphens in them easily too

Comment: I just ran your sample. In case user inputs convertible string, main_phone doesn't return as null at my side. Verified by Console.WriteLine(main_phone). Sorry if I misunderstood your objective.

Comment: @Ali.NET Try to run it and input "sodapop" and then when it gives you an error and asks for a number input any number. You'll see that it doesn't return the number , but instead it returns null.

Comment: you really don't want/need recursion.  You need a simple while loop that quits when input is valid, as in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that loops until a good match is produced, using regex validation

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}");
string phonenumber = Console.ReadLine();

while (!regex.IsMatch(phonenumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bad Input");
    phonenumber = Console.ReadLine();
}

return Convert.ToInt32(phonenumber.Replace("-",""));
```

which will match 5555555555 and 555-555-5555, and return the int value.

Comment: Ok, but since I don't want that just for phones I'll use @"\d+". But then what if the user types something like "555231409a"? how do I handle that whitout crashing the app?

Comment: That wouldn't crash the app at all, it would handle it fine

Answer (score 1):

How about you just read in as a string what the user puts in, replace all "-" with "", then check if it numeric and check length. No need to make a recursive method for such a simple task.

how about this

[VB.NET]

```
Function CheckPhoneNumber(ByVal Number As String) As String

Number = Number.Replace("-","")  
Number = Number.Replace("(","")
Number = Number.Replace(")","")

If Not IsNumeric(Number) Then
Return "Error"
Else
Return Number
End If

End Function
```

[C#]

```
public string CheckPhoneNumber(string Number)
{

        Number = Number.Replace("-", "");



        Number = Number.Replace("(", "");
        Number = Number.Replace(")", "");

    if (!Information.IsNumeric(Number)) {
        return "Error";
    } else {
        return Number;
    }

}
```

Comment: But then I'd have to send a message each time the user inputs something wrong, how am I gonna do that without recursion?

Comment: first of you should get your mind away from using recursion to this problem. Second why not just limit the number of times a user can try to put in a phone number. They should not need more than 2 tries to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using int.TryParse?

```
void Main()
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    int phone;
    while(!int.TryParse(input, out phone)){
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

To cleanup the input, you can replace the "-"

```
var input = Console.ReadLine().Replace("-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could strip out any extra characters ('+', '-', '#', '(', ')', and '*') then try

```
bool successful;
int result;
if(!int.tryparse(string, result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid phone number");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid phone number");
}
```

Or whatever you like.

Of course the alternative is to use REGEX. (note: I'm stealing this from Regex Hero found here: http://regexhero.net/tester/)

```
string strRegex = @"[+]?[\d][\d\s()-.]{8,}[\d]";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version of your code segment:

```
        static int? verifyParse(string str, string lable)
        {
            int? testedVar = TryParse(str);
            if (testedVar == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Este campo pode apenas conter dígitos de 0 à 9.");
                Console.Write(lable);
                int? newVal = verifyParse(Console.ReadLine(), lable);
                if (newVal != null)
                    return newVal;
                else
                    return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return testedVar;
            }
        }//End of verifyParse();
```